# Right and left limits of $\frac{\sqrt{\sin x^2}}x$ at 0

Tags: limits

Can someone help me to find left and right limits of $\frac{\sqrt{\sin x^2}}x$ at 0? When I draw the graph it is clear that left and right limits are 1 and $-1$, but don't know to show that in proper way.

Comment: Did the question change? The way it is written it is clear that both right and left limits are 0.

Comment: $sin x^2 \simeq x^2$ so it is $\simeq \sqrt x$ which tends to $0$.

Comment: The question was changed by last edit, the original one is $\frac{\sqrt{\sin x^2}}x$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that since $\sqrt {x^2}=|x|$, we have that

- for $x>0$

$$\frac{\sqrt{\sin x^2}}x= \sqrt{\frac{\sin x^2}{x^2}}\to\sqrt 1=1$$

- for $x<0$

$$\frac{\sqrt{\sin x^2}}x= -\sqrt{\frac{\sin x^2}{x^2}}\to-\sqrt 1=-1$$

Comment: Gimusi.All said.Nice.+1

Answer (score 0):

$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sqrt{\sin x^2}}x \simeq \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sqrt{x^2}}x=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{|x|}x$

For $x=0^+ : \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{|x|}x=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x}x=1$

For $x=0^- : \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{|x|}x=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{-x}x=-1$